# How to fix a logic in Python (for loop)

Tags: python

Here is a list in My Python code. I would like to separate a list by a break before and after None

```
lists = [

'a',
'b',
'c',
'None',
'd',
'e',
'e',
'f',
'None',
'g',
'h',
'i',
'i',
'i',
'None',
'aa',
'aa',
'aa',
'aa',
'aa',
'ab',
'ac',

]
```

So, Expected out would be:

```
out = ['a','b','c',], ['d','e','e','f',], ['g','h','i','i','i',], ['aa','aa','aa','aa','aa','ab','ac']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for hints on how to ask productive questions. `How to fix a logic in Python (for loop)` can you provide the code of your loop?

Comment: I couldn't implement any logic

Comment: Do you really have the string `"None"` and not `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lists = [<your data>]
out = []
temp = []
for item in lists:
    if item != 'None':
        temp.append(item)
    else:
        out.append(temp)
        temp = []
# Catch that list temp list
if temp:
    out.append(temp)
del temp
print(out)
```

> **OUTPUT**: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i'], ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac']]

Comment: I think you should add `if temp: out.append(temp)` after the loop. Otherwise, `temp` will contain the last chunk of data that isn't terminated by `'None'`. In this case `temp == ['aa','aa','aa','aa','aa','ab','ac']`.

Comment: We could even go with `del temp` and totally git rid of it.

Comment: That's not the point. Your current implementation doesn't take care of the last chunk of data, namely, `['aa','aa','aa','aa','aa','ab','ac']`.

Answer (score 5):

```
from itertools import groupby

items = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "None",
    "D",
    "E",
    "None",
    "F",
    "G",
    "H"
]

lists = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(items, key=lambda x: x != "None") if key]

print(lists)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H']]
```

Comment: perfect usage of the fact groupby yields the groups immediately whenever the key changes. this will also handle multiple consecutive `'None'`s properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your provided list to test my code.

**Code:**

```
result_list = []
temp_list = []
for elem in lists:
    if elem == "None":
        result_list.append(temp_list)
        temp_list = []
        continue
    temp_list.append(elem)
result_list.append(temp_list) if temp_list else None
print(result_list)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python test.py 
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i'], ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac']]
```